# Word for "dearly missed"

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> Smallville. The name belonged to her [...] hometown.

I thought about *yearned* but apparently using it in cases like [this](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&q=%22yearned%20hometown%22&oq=%22yearned%20hometown%22&gs_l=serp.3...31383.36248.0.36458.22.19.1.0.0.1.309.2498.0j6j5j1.12.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..16.6.1216.GtfkGWXi0kA) seems grammatically incorrect?

Comment: You could say "she [*yearned for (her) home (-town)*](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1366&bih=610&tbm=bks&q=%22yearned+for+home%22&oq=%22yearned+for+home%22&gs_l=serp.12...10063.11368.0.13154.5.5.0.0.0.0.149.647.0j5.5.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..4.1.144.UOlV8t1licw)

Comment: *Beloved* (dearly loved) might fit, which, in your context, can also suggest the idea of something you are missing.

Comment: @Josh61 but *beloved* doesn't have the connotation of missing something dearly, or nostalgia. Although if something weren't *beloved*, you wouldn't miss it.

Comment: I know , I just commented that in the given context it may also suggest nostalgia.

Comment: I think the word I see most often used in this context is "*lost*", even though the town is not literally lost (it's still the same place it's always been).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"her yearned hometown"? You bet it's grammatical**ly** incorrect. Yearned-for, possibly, though it's ugly. I can't think of anything good to go in your gap, but would ask why "dearly missed" needs to be replaced at all. It's only four syllables, after all, not something long and clunky.